# Cannot build package due to missing GCC headers in Buildroot (stdio.h)

Tags: gcc, buildroot, swupdate

Recently, I updated the Buildroot directory from 2019.11 to 2022.2 in order to build for a new board (RPi4B Rev1.5) and access the updated Linux kernel and headers. Unfortunately, I have been unable to build due to missing headers for the SWUpdate package.

An extract of the error is below. The full log can be found at [this link](https://paste.ack.tf/e1f1a8) (as it is long).

```
 CC      tools/swupdate-client.o
ipc/network_ipc-if.c:8:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
8 | #include <stdio.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~
ipc/network_ipc.c:9:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
9 | #include <stdio.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/haelyons/project_folder/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/arm- 
buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/10.3.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
             from /home/haelyons/project_folder/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot- 
linux-gnueabihf/10.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
             from parser/parse_external.c:10:
/home/haelyons/project_folder/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux- 
gnueabihf/10.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:195:15: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or 
directory
```

Essentially, as this is a package included with Buildroot, I am not sure if the issue is with my installation of GCC, or with the package itself referencing the incorrect folder. If possible, I would greatly appreciate some pointers in the right direction such as more tests that I could perform to diagnose this. Thanks, H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, it turns out this was an issue with the configuration path assigned within the Buildroot config. It was referring to the RPi3 configuration, which required a different kernel and GCC version. The fix involved the following:

```
make nconfig
# Navigate to: Target Packages > System Tools > SWUpdate Config Path
# Update the patch to the new board's config - BR2_EXTERNAL=<path>
make -C savedefconfig BR2_DEFCONFIG=../<config path>
```